# Rails db:create using PostgreSQL return PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, postgresql

I was following the tutorial to develop using react and rails from the [DigitalOcean Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-ruby-on-rails-project-with-a-react-frontend).

I have done

```
rails new rails_react_recipe -d=postgresql -T --webpack=react --skip-coffee
```

It created the directory with all the necessary tools - ruby and rails. 
Then the next step is to create the database

```
rails db:create
```

but it returned me the error below

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
Couldn't create 'rails_react_recipe_development' database. Please check your configuration.        
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have installed postgresql 12 for windows from https://www.postgresql.org/download/

I couldn't find any solution online. Help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the Postgres server for it to start accepting connections. Currently, you've probably downloaded Postgres, but not started it.

You could follow instructions here to learn how to start it on Windows: https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/10/how-to-start-stop-restart-postgresql-server.html